# Can I use font-size: calc(1px * 1vw) to get around compatibility issues?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, cross-browser

IE <= 8 doesn't support `font-size: 1vw` and the site I am developing for requires that I do.

If I do `calc(1px * 1vw)`, does that return a pixel value? Is my understanding of `calc()` right?

I am under the assumption that `font-sie: 1vw` doesn't work because IE doesn't know how to convert `vw` to `px`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is no because `calc()` is not supported on IE <= 8. https://caniuse.com/#search=calc()

The slightly longer answer is still no because you cannot multiply or divide by different units. Here's what the W3 docs say:

> At *, check that at least one side is number. If both sides are integer, resolve to . Otherwise, resolve to the type of the other side.
>
> At /, check that the right side is number. If the left side is integer, resolve to . Otherwise, resolve to the type of the left side.

(https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/#funcdef-calc)

Since `vw` won't work for IE8 (and neither will `em` or `rem`) the only thing I can think of is trying `%`.

If you can get away with a static font size on IE8 just add a fallback font size. That way modern browsers will read `1vw` and move on with their day, and IE8 will read it and say I'm a dinosaur and don't know what that is, so I'll go with your previous size (e.g. `16px`).

```
p {
  font-size: 16px;
  font-size: 1vw;
}
```

Comment: Amazing. Perfect answer. Thank you.